# Show $\{f^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent, where $S$ is connected and $f: S\to \mathbb F$ is non-constant continuous

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Question**: Let $S$ be a connected metric space and $F:= \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If $f: S \to F$ be a non-constant continuous function, show that the set $\{f^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$  is linearly independent.

**Attempt**: We consider $F:= \mathbb{C}$. Since $f$ is non constant on $S$, we must have $f(\alpha) \neq f(\beta)$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in S$.   Consider the function $N:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $N(\textbf{x})=|\textbf{x}-f(\alpha)|$. Evidently, $N$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$.

Thereby, $N\circ f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ must be continuous.

$N(f(S)) \subset \mathbb{R}$ must be a connected set. Further, $N(f(\alpha))=0$ and $N(f(\beta))>0$.

For any connected set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$,  $\forall \  x, y \in A$ with $x<y$, we must have $z\in A$, whenever $x<z<y$.

Hence, $\forall p \in (Nf(\alpha),Nf(\beta))=(0,Nf(\beta))$, we get at least one $y_p \in S$ such that $Nf(y_p)=p$. For any $p\neq q$ in $(0,N(f(\beta))$ we must have $f(y_p)\neq f(y_q)$ (By the definition of function). Therefore, $|\mathbb{C}|\geq |N^{-1}(0,N(f(\beta))\cap f(S)|\geq|(0,Nf(\beta))|$, but $|(0,Nf(\beta))|=|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{C}|$. Therefore, $|\mathbb{C}|= |N^{-1}(0,Nf(\beta))|=|N^{-1}(0,N(f(\beta))\cap f(S)|$

Now, assume towards a contradiction that $\{f^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$  is linearly dependent.

Therefore, $\exists$ a finite subset $\{f^{i_1},f^{i_2},...,f^{i_k}\}$ which is linearly dependent.

Consider $c_1f^{i_1}(x)+c_2f^{i_2}(x)+...+c_kf^{i_k}(x)=0 \ \forall x \in S$. Hence it holds $\forall x\in D :=(Nf)^{-1}(0,Nf(\beta))\subset S$. We put $f(x)=u$ for $x\in D$.

$c_1u^{i_1}+c_2u^{i_2}+...+c_ku^{i_k}=0$ is a polynomial of degree $\max\{i_1,...,i_k\}=r$ in $f(D)$ and we have $|f(D)|=|\mathbb{C}|$. The equality is possible only when the polynomial is identically equal to $0$, i.e. $c_1=...=c_k=0$. [Since $f(D)$ is uncountable and thus the number of root becomes $>r$, which is possible only when it is identical to $0$].

Therefore, $\{f^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: What is $f^i$ in relation to $f$? Does it mean $f^i(s) = (f(s))^i$?

Comment: @Joppy, That's what I interpreted. There was an additional part to the question: Further if $f(s)\neq 0$ for all $s \in S$, prove that $\{f^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is also linearly independent. So, depending on the context, I take it as $f^i(s)=(f(s))^i$.

Comment: What do you mean by $|\mathbb{C}|$ and $|\mathbb{R}|$? They are not established notation.

Comment: @Chrystomath, cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

Comment: Is the paragraph before last using some result you already proved?

Comment: @Chrystomath, I'll update it right now. Have a look. I need to clarify how it is identical to $0$.

Comment: I get a bit lost in the middle of your argument, but I think that it is mostly good. A lemma I think could simplify most of the argument: if $K$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ that contains at least two points, then $K$ contains infinitely many points. Then assuming a linear dependence, you end up with a polynomial with infinitely many roots, which must be the zero polynomial. This lemma can be easily proven I think (via contrapositive: if $K$ is finite with $|K| \geq 2$, then $K$ is disconnected)

Comment: The argument needs to be made tighter. I'm also lost in the middle, but it seems that $f(D)$ is in an open disk, so the limit point could well be at the boundary.

Comment: Suppose, $K$ is connected and finite with $|K|\geq 2$ and $K \subset \mathbb{C}$. Now, the open balls in $(K,d_K)$ are of the form $B^{d_\mathbb{C}}_r(p)\cap K=B^{d_K}_r(p)$. Taking $r<\displaystyle\frac{\min\{|k_i-k_j|:i\neq j \}}{2}$ we can write $K=\displaystyle\cup_{k_i}B^{d_K}_r (k_i) $ and $B^{d_K}_r (k_i) \cap B^{d_K}_r (k_j)=\phi$ for $i\neq j$ and $B^{d_K}_r (k_j)=\{k_j\}$.

Therefore it can be written as a union of disjoint open sets, i.e. not connected.

Comment: @Joppy is the method correct?

Comment: @Chrystomath https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2721919/389992 I think this will do...

Comment: The question is not whether there is a limit point, but whether that limit point is part of $f(D)$. Joppy's comment gives a neater solution. It only depends on the fact that a polynomial has a finite number of zeros.

Comment: @Chrystomath, I have corrected my answer. One more thing, could you please check out the lemma I attempted to prove? (As suggested by Joppy).

Comment: The proof looks good - note that it works for any finite subset of any metric space, showing that the points are all both closed and open, so they form the connected components of the finite set.